# Restore terminal background in ubuntu unity

Tags: unity, command-line, gnome-terminal, desktop-background

Here how my terminal look, it's ugly. and I want to restore it to the Purple background with the gray test color. Like the default installation.

[image]

Comment: What terminal is it? `gnome-terminal`? Or any other emaulator?

Comment: @ByteCommander I'd bet it is terminator.

Comment: Never used terminator. I always stuck to the Gnome Terminal Emulator and was happy with it... So if that is the case, I'm out.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using [Terminator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/terminator/) which is not the default ubuntu terminal application.

You can try and find the default terminal by Searching for it in the Launcher (Can be opened using the Super Key (Usually with a windows logo on).

Or you can run

```
gnome-terminal
```

from your current command line.

If neither of these work then for some reason it has been uninstalled

To install it run

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

The last option if you are absolutely stuck is do do a right click then preferences to edit the colour scheme to what you want it to be.

If you can boot it from the terminal but not the launcher, let me know so that I can create a desktop icon for you so that you can start it without using a terminal if you don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't give up on Terminator so easily. It is more powerful than GNOME Terminal by a mile. To set the background:

1. Right click on the terminal area (anywhere in the black area), and click on *Preferences*.
2. Click on the *Profiles* tab, and then in the *Colours* sub tab:
   [image]
3. Either make sure *Use colours from system theme* is selected, or if it is already selected, uncheck it and set custom colours.